# Is the input from local file system on each node or only the driver node?

Tags: hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

Hadoop accepts input from local file system, but I found no clear instruction from nowhere that whether the input is from the local file systems of all the nodes or only from the local file system of the driver node?

In Hadoop Streaming, the `-input` option seems to mean the input from all the nodes with the given file name, I would like also to confirm this

Answer (score 0):

The `-input` option for hadoop streaming isn't from the local file system, it should be an HDFS path.

So because this is an HDFS path the files/directories will be available to the MapReduce job that gets executed.